# In the account in Numbers 31, how would the Israelite soldiers have known which women had had sex and which women did not?

Tags: numbers

The text records Moses as having said,

"Now therefore kill every male among the little ones, and kill every woman that hath known man by lying with him." Numbers 31:17

The implication is that the women who had had sex were the ones who had engaged in the orgies with the men of Israel. This makes sense, since the Israelites were attacking only a group of Midianites, as indicated by the fact that there were Midianites who interacted with the Israelites after this event. But how would the Israelites have known which women had had sex and which women did not?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the plague was some form of venereal disease. The [symptoms would have been visible within days](https://www.verywell.com/how-long-before-std-symptoms-appear-3133026) within the Israelite population, and well established in the locals.

Comment: @enegue,I believe the OP is really asking about how did they identify the virgins

Comment: @collenndhlovu The implication is the virgins wouldn't have symptoms of a sexually transmitted infection.

Comment: @enegue Thank you for your answer. That makes sense. However, it is, by nature, a speculative answer. If it is the case, though, that the plague was a venereal disease, and that it affected the Midianite women as (as it seems to have been directed at the Israelites), then this would answer the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The words describing the women are וְכָל־אִשָּׁ֗ה יֹדַ֥עַת אִ֛ישׁ. The word יֹדַעַת is a participle, so a more literal translation might be *every woman knowing a man*. This doesn't imply that the woman actually had intercourse, but that she potentially could have.

A similar construction with the participle is Deuteronomy 22:8, which says כִּֽי־יִפֹּ֥ל הַנֹּפֵ֖ל מִמֶּֽנּוּ, literally *for the falling one will fall from it*, where someone is already called a "falling one" only because he can potentially fall. Similarly, the redeemer (גֹאֵל) of Ruth 3-4 is called a redeemer because he was a potential redeemer, not because he actually ended up redeeming the field. And in Amos 9:1, he says that a fleeing person (נָס) won't be able to flee; since he won't be able to flee, describing him as a fleeing person is only appropriate since he could *potentially* flee.

What the verse is saying is not to kill the young girls who aren't at the age to have had intercourse (Numbers 31:18). The older women were killed based on their potential to have had intercourse, and not because they specifically had intercourse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't it true, though, that children can have intercourse (although they shouldn't, of course)? Perhaps, based on this explanation, women who passed a certain age were killed based on the assumption that they had intercourse, and this were involved in the sex rituals.

Comment: @CMK Yes, I think the question is who could potentially have been involved in the incident with Baal Peor (see 31:16), so the age range would depend on who was involved there

Comment: וְכֹל֙ הַטַּ֣ף בַּנָּשִׁ֔ים אֲשֶׁ֥ר - v18 literally "But all the children among the women who..."

Comment: "The older women were killed based on their potential to have had intercourse, and not because they specifically had intercourse." Isn't killing the righteous along with the wicked frowned upon biblically? Its not like as if the women who previously incited the Israelites to sin at Baal-Peor stopped being evil at the moment off their execution, thus making it hard to differentiate between those who had sex and virgins. They were pretty bold in following Balaam's counsel to lead the Israelites astray so maybe they were still wearing their ritual (?) garments from their crimes at Numbers 25:1-3.

Comment: @AngelusVastator The text mentions no ritual garments, much less that they were still worn after whatever time passed during a census and a few chapters of new laws

Comment: I'm not saying that 100% the Midianite female criminals could be identified by their ritual garments. Hell, they've could had marked their flesh to show their allegiances, another pagan custom. All I'm saying is that Moses knew right away based on his quick observation of the captives the Israelite soldiers took back.

Comment: And that's something that could be deduced based on appearance. It wasn't likely for Moses to be able to look into the hearts of those women to determine their  guilt. Even if this was something he asked God to help him with, there's no implicit indication of that in the Bible.

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be as simple as a visible cultural indicator like a ring, band, piercing, or tattoo which indicates the female is "off the market", or no longer available for virgin marriage.

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense.